# In Unity3D, how can I improve image clarity?

Tags: unity, sprites, rendering

The same images that appear clearly in Adobe Flash appear blurry in Unity.

My game uses quads, cubes and sprites. I've tried the game on Android, iPhone, Mac  and PC, but the image appears poor-quality on all of them.

A sample screenshot:

[image]

What can I do about this?

Comment: is this image for gui or model texture?

Comment: What is your target platform?

Comment: I made a 2d game using quad,cube and sprite . Platforms Android ,iPhone , Mac ,PC . Every platform have poor clarity

Comment: @LijuThomas Are you talking about texture filtering?

Comment: No [Code Clown](http://stackoverflow.com/users/378386/code-clown)  , i already try texture type and  filtering mode but no result

Comment: got screenshots?

Comment: Make sure all textures have power-of-two dimensions. Filtering/compression work better (some compression formats won't work at all otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get all needed informations in the official documentation: see [Manual: 2D Textures](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html).

Basically you can control the "quality" of textures by tweaking the compression format and filtering mode.

Answer (score 1):

If you need good image quality you can use Format: Truecolor or ARGB 32 with an high Max Size and avoid compression:

[image]

You can try playing with Filter Mode and Aniso Level too in the advanced settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have mitmaps enabled on your resources, you may be inadvertently using a lower quality image. You can try disabling mitmaps on each resource to see if your image quality increases.

Furthermore in Edit>Project Settings>Quality you can set quality flags of your application.

You may also want to make sure that your resources are a large enough size, and that you're not blowing up a 16x16 image onto a large texture for example.